# convert vector of strings/doubles to arrays

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am using matheval library. Its functions take c-style parameters, for example:

```
    #include<matheval.h>

    char * evaluator_evaluate(void * evaluator, int count, char **names, double *values);
```

In my case, I want to convert std::vector of names and std::vector of values to char  ** and double *

Also, every name correspond to a unique value, and there could be repetitions. What is the best way to arrange names and values elegantly in terms of data structures? For now, I use vectors, and both contains repetitions.

**Edit**  Please keep in mind that order of names and values matters and should match.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using STL Vectors? Are you trying to get rid of duplicates? Do you want/need to preserve the order of your data?

Comment: What format are your input vectors stored in? E.g. vector<std::string> ?

Comment: yes, order matters, vectors are from STL. It'd be nice to get rid of duplicates. Let me edit the questions appropriately. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally, the standard requires that a `vector<>` is equivalent to an array. You can take the address of `vector[0]` and the resulting pointer will point to a contiguous area of memory where the data is stored, in the same order as the vector. This pointer is valid until or unless the `vector<>` is resized.

For `std::string` values (or any other object, for that matter), though, you will only get an array of `string` objects.

Comment: greyfade, that nicely solves my first problem with doubles. What about the second? any suggestions?

Comment: All I can suggest is to allocate a char** array and initialize it with the string.c_str() pointers. That may cause problems if the C function expects to be able to change them, though.

Comment: Perhaps, I can use another data structure. It's a fairly common problem -- I am  sure there is a solution :)

Comment: Probably, but that is the only idea I have for strings. Good luck to you.